# Blank space on the top and bottom in Iphone 6.0 simulator retina display 4.0 inches

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, layout, retina-display

I have an application with an apple connect screen . I am running it in iPhone simulator 6.0 with 4.0 inches retina display. 
The problem is that it is showing black layout in the top and bottom. 
The layout is not adjusting and free black space is coming in the top as well as in the bottom. 
Any solution for the issue?

Comment: u need to add a default image for 4 inches screen..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set default-568h@2x.png image becouse iphone5 screen is 4 inch and we can put all images consider as 3.5 inch screen

please read this [coderwall](http://coderwall.com/p/7wgfqw)  about more clearly understanding of image resolution

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7 Beta 6
The Solution is,

Select your Project on the left>>In General Settings
Under "App Icons and Launch Images" 
In "Launch Screen File" select main.storyboard

[image]

This should remove black screen on top and bottom.